# How to upload an Android project into SVN repository & which files to ignore?

Tags: android, svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to share project with my team members. Anybody please help me how to upload an Android project into SVN. Which files should be uploaded and which ones to ignore?

Thanks.

Comment: Tortoise SVN is an SVN client, you do not upload files into it.

Comment: Thank you for reply, actually i put total project in online repository, we are getting errors while team persons are accessing the repository. what i am asking is which files are put in the online repository.

Comment: OK, there you go. I edited the question for you :) Basically, you need to upload `assets` (if existst), `libs/` (if exists),`res/`, `src/`, `Android.mk` (if exists), `AndroidManifest.xml` and `project.properties` (if building using Eclipse)

Comment: Thank you Shoe rat, and one more question, i am using Sherlock Library, my project is referencing to Sherlock library (it is in my workspace), while uploading the above files(mentioned by you) how can i work with workspace libraries.

Comment: I would not upload libraries (especially if they are open source as is the case with ActionBarSherlock); I would just a README file and put notes on what libraries are used and how/where to get them.

Comment: Hi Shoe Rat, thank you for your comment, i uploaded file what u said previously, its working fine after download from repository, in my project i am using sherlock library, i imported these library into my workspace, when i add these library to my project it is not adding, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all directories except the bin folder and gen folder. When other team members grab the project from the repository to their local workspace, these files will be re-created automatically when they compile the project.

Comment: Thank you Sound Conception.